# Assign int to JButtons to make method more efficient?

Tags: java, swing, icons, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm making a game with 9 JButtons that each do basically the same function. How can I make it so that these buttons each have an int (0-8) attached to them so I don't have to write the same method 9 times? Here is the method as it is currently:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource() == cardOne) {
            if(boardArray.get(0).selected == false) {
                getPath(0);
                buttons[0].setIcon(selectedIcon);
                boardArray.get(0).selected = true;

            }else{
                boardArray.get(0).selected = false;
                buttons[0].setIcon(boardArray.get(0).cardImage);
            }

        }
        if(e.getSource() == cardTwo) {
            if(boardArray.get(1).selected == false) {
                getPath(1);
                buttons[1].setIcon(selectedIcon);
                boardArray.get(1).selected = true;
            }else{
                boardArray.get(1).selected = false;
                buttons[1].setIcon(boardArray.get(1).cardImage);
            }

        }
        if(e.getSource() == cardThree) {
            if(boardArray.get(2).selected == false) {
                getPath(2);
                buttons[2].setIcon(selectedIcon);
                boardArray.get(2).selected = true;
            }else{
                boardArray.get(2).selected = false;
                buttons[2].setIcon(boardArray.get(2).cardImage);
            }

        }
        if(e.getSource() == cardFour) {
            if(boardArray.get(3).selected == false) {
                getPath(3);
                buttons[3].setIcon(selectedIcon);
                boardArray.get(3).selected = true;
            }else{
                boardArray.get(3).selected = false;
                buttons[3].setIcon(boardArray.get(3).cardImage);
            }

        }
        if(e.getSource() == cardFive) {
            if(boardArray.get(4).selected == false) {
                getPath(4);
                buttons[4].setIcon(selectedIcon);
                boardArray.get(4).selected = true;

            }else{
                boardArray.get(4).selected = false;
                buttons[4].setIcon(boardArray.get(4).cardImage);
            }

        }
        if(e.getSource() == cardSix) {
            if(boardArray.get(5).selected == false) {
                getPath(5);
                buttons[5].setIcon(selectedIcon);
                boardArray.get(5).selected = true;
            }else{
                boardArray.get(5).selected = false;
                buttons[5].setIcon(boardArray.get(5).cardImage);
            }

        }
        if(e.getSource() == cardSeven) {
            if(boardArray.get(6).selected == false) {
                getPath(6);
                buttons[6].setIcon(selectedIcon);
                boardArray.get(6).selected = true;
            }else{
                boardArray.get(6).selected = false;
                buttons[6].setIcon(boardArray.get(6).cardImage);
            }

        }
        if(e.getSource() == cardEight) {
            if(boardArray.get(7).selected == false) {
                getPath(7);
                buttons[7].setIcon(selectedIcon);
                boardArray.get(7).selected = true;
            }else{
                boardArray.get(7).selected = false;
                buttons[7].setIcon(boardArray.get(7).cardImage);
            }

        }
        if(e.getSource() == cardNine) {
            if(boardArray.get(8).selected == false) {
                getPath(8);
                buttons[8].setIcon(selectedIcon);
                boardArray.get(8).selected = true;
            }else{
                boardArray.get(8).selected = false;
                buttons[8].setIcon(boardArray.get(6).cardImage);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You could...

Associate each `JButton` with an `int` via a `Map` of some kind...

```
private Map<JButton, Integer> mapButtons;
//...
mapButtons = new HashMap<JButton, Integer>(25);
mapButtons.put(cardOne, 1);
```

Then you could just extract the integer value within the `ActionListener`

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source instanceof JButton) {
        JButton btn = (JButton)source;
        int value = mapButtons.get(btn);
```

If you don't want to introduce another object into your code...

## You could...

Associate a value via the buttons `clientProperty` property...

```
btn.putClientProperty("value", 1);

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source instanceof JButton) {
        JButton btn = (JButton)source;
        value = (Integer)btn.getClientProperty("value");
```

## You could...

Use the buttons `actionCommand` property, which expects a `String`, but you could cast it to a `int` value.  It's a little more messy, but would get the job done...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [setActionCommand()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setActionCommand(java.lang.String)) to set to each button its corresponding number and in the `actionPerformed` method call `e.getActionCommand()` and parse that `String` to an `int`

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to create an inner class that implements `ActionListener` like so:

```
  public class ButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {
    private final int boardElement;

    ButtonActionListener(int boardElement) {
      this.boardElement = boardElement;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if (boardArray.get(boardElement).selected == false) {
        getPath(boardElement);
        buttons[boardElement].setIcon(selectedIcon);
        boardArray.get(boardElement).selected = true;
      } else {
        boardArray.get(boardElement).selected = false;
        buttons[boardElement].setIcon(boardArray.get(boardElement).cardImage);
      }
    }
  }
```

Then when you create the `JButton` objects, add an instance of this action listener with the required index:

```
  // Just an example, it's not clear to me how the buttons[] array is created
  for (int i = 0; i < boardArray.size(); ++i) {
    buttons[i] = new JButton();
    // Other stuff as needed
    buttons[i].addActionListener(new ButtonActionListener(i));
  }
```